# how to post articles with categories in blogger with zend Gdata 1.11

Tags: api, blogger, zend-gdata

how to post articles with categories in blogger with zend **ZendGdata 1.11.11**

Answer (score 0):

```
$labels = $entry->getCategory();
$newLabel = $gdClient->newCategory('testlabel2', 'http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#');
$labels[] = $newLabel; // Append the new label to the list of labels. 
$entry->setCategory($labels);
```